# Use properties from JSONB Array inside a UPDATE WHERE Clause Postgres 10

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a similar table to what is shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE jsontesting (id int, jsondata jsonb)

INSERT INTO jsontesting VALUES( 1,'[  
   {  
      "value":1,
      "content":{  
         "en-US":"A. This is response A",
         "es-MX":"A. Esta es la respuesta A"

      }
   },
   {  
      "value":2,
      "content":{  
         "en-US":"A. This is response B",
         "es-MX":"Esta es la respuesta B"
      }
   }
]'),
(2, '[
   {  
      "value":1,
      "content":{  
         "en-US":"A. This is response C",
         "es-MX":"A. Esta es la respuesta C"

      }
   },
   {  
      "value":2,
      "content":{  
         "en-US":"A. This is response D",
         "es-MX":"Esta es la respuesta D"
      }
   }
]')
```

I'd like to update this table based on value properties:

```
    UPDATE jsontesting 
    SET    jsondata = Jsonb_set(jsondata, '{0,"content","en-US"}', value_r) 
    FROM   (SELECT 1                        AS id, 
           1                        AS key_response, 
           'This is new response Z' AS value_r) z 
    WHERE  Jsonb_array_elements_text(jsondata) ->> 'value' = z.keys_response 
   AND id = z.id;
```

> There is error:
>   [Code: , SQL State: 0A000]  ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
>     Position: 181

Is there any way to update postgresql jsonb array based on properties inside this json?